# Access html element in media modal with jQuery

Tags: images, jquery

I'm using the following code to add the required attribute to a textarea tag.
HTML:

```
<label class="setting" data-setting="caption">
        <span class="name">Beschriftung</span>
        <textarea></textarea>
</label>
```

JavaScript:

```
jQuery(function(){
       jQuery("label[data-setting='caption']").find("textarea").prop('required',true);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qp30Ljvo/

When I add an image to a text field in a post wordpress opens the media modal.

When I inspect the media modal with right click -> Inspect I can navigate to the following HTML element.

```
<label class="setting" data-setting="caption">
        <span class="name">Beschriftung</span>
        <textarea></textarea>
</label>
```

How can I make my JavaScript code run the jQuery function on the media modal?

[image: media modal]

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do? Should you be setting the caption somewhere in a Gutenberg object model rather than directly on the page?

Comment: I'm trying to change the element <textarea></textarea> to <textarea required></textarea>. I know the jQuery syntax. I don't know how to access the page which contains the html element.

Answer (score 0):

```
(function($){
//since only one label with data-setting='caption' exists, use this selector
    $("[data-setting=caption]").children('textarea').attr('required', true);
    })(jQuery);
```

I'm more curious as to how adding this would affect anything since these labels are not inside a `<form>` element?

Comment: I can't test this, but your probably right. Adding the required attribute might not affect anything. I thought I could make caption a required field by adding the required attribute.